# How to evaluate a list of tasks

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have 2 entities: `Topic.cs`, `Lecture.cs`, a model: `TopicModel.cs` and an asynchronous repo call `repo.GetAllLecturesAsync(string topicId)`. The contents of these are intuitive.

I need to get all lectures from a repo class asynchronously and put them into a topic model. I have the following code:

```
List<TopicModel> topicModels = topics.Select(async topic => new TopicModel
{
    Lectures = (await repo.GetAllLecturesAsync(topic.Id)).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

This code generates the following error:

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<Task<TopicModel>>' to 'List<TopicModel>'"
```

How do I get rid of the intermediate `Task` in there?

**Edit:**

`topics` is a type of `List<Topic>`.

`GetAllLecturesAsync()` returns `Task<IEnumerable<Lecture>>`.

`TopicModel` has a single property `public List<Lecture> Lectures{ get; set; }`

Comment: Try something like (untested) `Lectures = (await repo.GetAllLecturesAsync(topic.Id)).Select(task => task.Result).ToList()`

Comment: Your idea is right, you just have to add .Select(task => task.Result) after the first select like this: List<TopicModel> topicModels = topics.Select(async topic => new TopicModel
{
    Lectures = (await repo.GetAllLecturesAsync(topic.Id)).ToList()
}).Select(task => task.Result).ToList();

Fix your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need the extra `ToList()` in there. `ToList()` is an `IEnumerable<T>` extension method, as is `Select()`. You should be able to call `Select()` on whatever you are calling `ToList()` on and avoid enumerating the `IEnumerable<T>` until you need to convert it into a list at the end.

Comment: Oh I see now, my confusion was because you didn't indicate where the line was being thrown, I assumed it was from the property assignment. Fixing my answer now.

Comment: Deleted my answer. I don't I understand async / await enough to provide an adequate answer. I think your code was flawed in a way I couldn't recognize and assumed it was just a type mismatch. Attempting to fix my answer with your suggestion just added confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___0___):

```
TopicModel[] topicModels = await Task.WhenAll(topics
    .Select(async topic => new TopicModel
    {
        Lectures = (await repo.GetAllLecturesAsync(topic.Id)).ToList()
    }));
```

By default `Task.WhenAll` returns an array, but if `List` is necessary you can call `ToList` on the result.

Comment: This is correct. However, this call is in a few more select statements. When I try to apply this to my code, I end up with 3 additional await Task.WhenAll and 2 existing non-async expressions become async which makes the code look like a mess. @Jacob Huckins 's approach is more object-oriented friendly. Thanks anyways. I appreciate knowing this.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul can you put whole snippet somewhere?

Comment: I don't want you to get lost in the details so, [here](https://github.com/m-azyoksul/EmptyRepo/blob/master/example.cs) is a detailed enough version.